# Read vehicle speed from Isuzu D-Max 2015

Tags: obd-ii, elm-327, isuzu

I'm using an OBD reader with Elm327 v1.5 chip. I have made a software that reads vehicle speed (pid 010d). This software works ok on VW Transporter and some other cars but not on Isuzu D-max MY 2013->

The software tries the different protocols by selecting one protocol and then requesting pid 010d. If getting a valid response the selected protocol is kept and used when requesting next pid.

The problem with Isuzu D-Max 2013-> is that I do not get any valid response on any protocol. I have also tested with a software called OBD Auto Doctor and I got the same result.

The tested protocols and response messages are:

SAE J1850 PWM (41.6 kbit/s) Resp: NO DATA

SAE J1850 VPW (10.4 kbit/s) Resp:FB ERROR

ISO 9141-2 (5 baud init, 10.4 kbit/s) Resp:INIT: BUS ERROR

ISO 14230-4 KWP (5 baud init, 10.4 kbit/s) Resp: INIT: BUS ERROR

ISO 14230-4 KWP (fast init, 10.4 kbit/s) Resp: INIT: BUS ERROR

ISO 15765-4 CAN (11 bit ID, 500 kbit/s) Resp: CAN ERROR

ISO 15765-4 CAN (29 bit ID, 500 kbit/s) Resp: CAN ERROR

ISO 15765-4 CAN (11 bit ID, 250 kbit/s) Resp: CAN ERROR

ISO 15765-4 CAN (29 bit ID, 250 kbit/s) Resp: CAN ERROR

Is there anyone that has experience of ELM327 an Isuzu Dmax 2013 or newer. What protocol is this vehicle using? And does the vehicle follow the OBD standard?

Comment: Have you the opportunity to try on another Isuzu? Just to check whether you just have a car with a faulty obd.

Comment: Unfortenatly I do not have another Isuzu to test on. I have checked that the OBD connector is properly inserted.

Comment: I added longer delay when waiting for responce from the vehicle and that solved the problem. ATST64  (64*4 = 256ms)